Individual callouts from queueable apex
I have the below code sample which is calling multiple callouts from queueable execute method.
Is it ok if I'm using below approach?
Process: after bulk insert of account records, I'm collecting all the accountids into a set and sending it to below queueable class for the callout
public class AccountApiCallQueueable implements Queueable {
    // List of AccountIds to be processed
    private List<Id> accountIds;
 
    // Constructor to accept the AccountIds
    public AccountApiCallQueueable(List<Id> accountIds) {
        this.accountIds = accountIds;
    }
 
    // The execute method that runs the logic
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Loop through each AccountId and make the API call
        for (Id accountId : accountIds) {
            sendAccountIdToExternalApi(accountId);
        }
    }
 
    // Method to send a single AccountId to the external API
    private void sendAccountIdToExternalApi(Id accountId) {
        // Construct the API URL and payload (using the single AccountId)
        String apiUrl = 'https://api.example.com/validateAccount';  // Replace with actual API URL
        String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{'accountId' => accountId});
 
        // Create an HTTP request to the external API
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(jsonPayload);
 
        // Send the HTTP request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
 
        // Handle the response from the external API
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('API response for AccountId ' + accountId + ': ' + res.getBody());
        } else {
            System.debug('API call failed for AccountId ' + accountId + ' with status: ' + res.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}


Take a look at this previous Q&A for some details around why future, Queueable and Batchable should not be launched from a trigger and how you can use Platform Events to help here. Note, too, that doing as many callouts per Queueable execution is generally best as there are daily async limits.

In order to do a callout from a Queueable, it must implement the Database.AllowsCallouts interface, otherwise it will throw an exception. Docs

Apex allows HTTP and web service callouts from queueable jobs, if they implement the Database.AllowsCallouts marker interface. In queueable jobs that implement this interface, callouts are also allowed in chained queueable jobs.

Moreover callouts have several limits and in your case the main ones are:

A single Apex transaction can make a maximum of 100 callouts to an HTTP request or an API call.
The maximum cumulative timeout for callouts by a single Apex transaction is 120 seconds. This time is additive across all callouts invoked by the Apex transaction.
The default timeout is 10 seconds. A custom timeout can be defined for each callout. The minimum is 1 millisecond and the maximum is 120,000 milliseconds.

Keep in mind that triggers execute on batches of 200 records at a time. So a bulk insert of 1000 records cause a trigger to fire multiple times, once for each 200 records. Therefore you will enqueue multiple jobs, each one with 200 Ids in the accountIds list and even if the callout will take less than a second to execute, that transaction will thorw an exception once it try to run the 101st callout due to the limits listed before.
Anyway a more realistic timeout for each callout will be greater than one second, that's why you have to take into account the second limit I listed. I.E. if each one takes 2s, you can only run 60 callouts.
Finally if a single callout takes more than 10s, you must increase the default timeout. Currently you didn't set a custom timeout, so you're keeping the default one, which is fine in many cases.
If you can modify the code on the server exposing that API, I would suggest to ingest a list of Id, instead of a single one (you should bulkify APIs too), this way you could call that API just one time with every Id in the single queueable transaction. Of course in this case you probably will need to increase the default timeout of the callout.
If not, to handle those limits you should check how many callout you could handle in single transaction due to the timeout, then extract at most that value from accountIds adding them to a new list and looping over the new one, finally, if accountIds is not empty, you should chain your queueable.
I.E. if the average time for each callout is 3s, you can choose 4s as conservative value and build up a local list with at most 30 Ids (or you could catch the timeout exception from the callout).
Here's a code to handle at most N Ids.
public class AccountApiCallQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    // List of AccountIds to be processed
    private final List<Id> accountIds;
    private final Integer scopeSize;
 
    // Constructor to accept the AccountIds
    public AccountApiCallQueueable(List<Id> accountIds) {
        this.accountIds = accountIds;
        scopeSize = 30; // This value could be stored in a Custom Metadata Type record
    }
 
    // The execute method that runs the logic
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Create the new lis
        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        Integer i = 0;
        // Move at most N ids from the instance variable to the local one
        while (!accountIds.isEmpty() && i < scopeSize) {
            ids.add(accountIds.remove(0));
            i++;
        }
        // Loop through each AccountId and make the API call
        for (Id accountId : ids) {
            sendAccountIdToExternalApi(accountId);
        }
        
        // Chain the queueable until the original list is not empty
        if (!accountIds.isEmpty() && !Test.isRunningTest()) {
            System.enqueueJob(this);
        }
    }
 
    // Method to send a single AccountId to the external API
    private void sendAccountIdToExternalApi(Id accountId) {
        // Construct the API URL and payload (using the single AccountId)
        String apiUrl = 'https://api.example.com/validateAccount';  // Replace with actual API URL
        String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{'accountId' => accountId});
 
        // Create an HTTP request to the external API
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(jsonPayload);
 
        // Send the HTTP request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
 
        // Handle the response from the external API
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('API response for AccountId ' + accountId + ': ' + res.getBody());
        } else {
            System.debug('API call failed for AccountId ' + accountId + ' with status: ' + res.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}

